# mdfind command on Debian Buster 10 but can't build index

Tags: linux, macos, debian, locate, mdfind

I have installed the mdfind package `mdfinder.app_0.9.4-1+b2_amd64.deb` on Debian 10 Buster.

The command `mdfind` comes classically from MacOS X but when I did an `apt-cache search mdfind`, I got this suggestion of package. Usually, I am using locate on Linux and I was surprising to find this package.

So, the command mdfind is available but unfortunately, at the execution, I get to look for a simple file :

```
$ mdfind README

mdfind: <NSException: 0x5575e031c7c0> NAME:NSInvalidArgumentException REASON:unable to parse the attribute name INFO:(null)
```

Normally, on MacOS systems, we can reindex all the Volume by `mdutil` tool but impossible to find it on Debian 10 buster.

**What does this error above correspond to ? Is it linked with the fact that I didn't build the index of all my hard disk** (like the equivalent of `locate` command with `updatedb` command) **?**

Any suggestion would be fine

Comment: Try : `mdfind -name README`

Comment: @harrymc If I have just created for example a `touch README33` and do after a `mdfind -name README33`, `mdfind` returns nothing. That's why I would like to have the same behavior than MacOS Catalina (on MacOS systems, `mdfind -name README33` returns a result). So I would like to launch a daemon or something else to have a result on Debian 10 Buster.

Comment: Does mdfind never find anything, or does it need time to index?

Comment: I think it doesn't return anything since I need to index all my hard disk but `mdutil` command doesn't exist on Debian 10 buster and I don't know how to index all (unlikely to MacOS where `mdutil`  or daemon exist). I can't launch the daemon `gmds` in the answer below.

Comment: @harrymc you made confusions between `mdfind` to locate files/dirs and `mbfind` (which is about music).

Comment: No, I call the `mdfind` command corresponding to `mdfind` tool on MacOS to find quickly files and directories.

Comment: I deleted my comments above. According to my research, in addition to `mdfinder.app`, you also need `gworkspace.app` to do the indexing, and perhaps Sqlite. You need to enable it in the SystemPreferences application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, installing the package `mdfinder.app` by itself
is not enough.

This package is part of the
[GWorkspace - GNUstep Workspace Manager](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/gworkspace.app/GWorkspace.1.en.html).
You need to download and install it from the
[Package gworkspace.app page](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gworkspace.app).
Sqlite is probably also required for database maintenance.

After installation and reboot, you also need to enable it in the
SystemPreferences application.
Documentation is sparse on what needs to be enabled or where,
so you will need to search for an item bearing one of the keywords
from the description of
[mdfinder.app](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mdfinder.app):

> **MDFinder** is a an application to search items already indexed by the **GWMetadata** indexing system, a **GNUstep** implementation of MacOS X's proprietary Spotlight. Searches can be saved and are automatically updated if the corresponding files change. Indexing is done in the background and is switched off by default. To enable it and configure the search path, use the dedicated module in the SystemPreferences application.

Answer (score 0):

Extract of `man MDFinder`

> ```
>    There are several accompanying programs which normally are not intended
>    to be invoked directly by the user.  Some of them run as
>    daemons and are launched automatically.  Here is a short description:
>
>
> gmds
>    This daemon is responsible for maintaining the indexing database,
>    located at $HOME/GNUstep/Library/gmds.
> ```

So `gmds` will be start when you start your GNUstep env.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I lauche the command `gmds` (with user and root) : `2020-05-20 16:44:19.215 gmds[217782:217782] unable to create: /home/fab/GNUstep/Library/gmds` :  it seems that `gmds` expects  a directory `Library` like on MacOS Catalina. How to circumvent this issue ?